# Adonis 5.0 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

I am trying to setup lucid on adonis 5.0 after installation using `node ace invoke @adonisjs/lucid`

OS: windows 10
node version: 14.6.1
npx version: 6.14.12

**Expected Result**

--Set up lucid

**Actual Result**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

1 leven

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\testapp\node_modules\@adonisjs\ace\node_modules\leven\index.js:14
```

2 anonymous

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\testapp\node_modules\@adonisjs\ace\build\src\Kernel\index.js:298
```

3 Kernel.getSuggestions

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\testapp\node_modules\@adonisjs\ace\build\src\Kernel\index.js:297
```

4 Kernel.execMain

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\testapp\node_modules\@adonisjs\ace\build\src\Kernel\index.js:169
```

5 Kernel.handle

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\testapp\node_modules\@adonisjs\ace\build\src\Kernel\index.js:477
```

6 App.handle

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\testapp\node_modules\@adonisjs\core\build\src\Ignitor\Ace\App\index.js:286
```

7 Ace.handle

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\testapp\node_modules\@adonisjs\core\build\src\Ignitor\Ace\index.js:33
```

**Update**

Here is the code in my package.json file as requested in the comment section.

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node ace build --production",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "node ace serve --watch",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext=.ts",
    "format": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@adonisjs/assembler": "^5.0.1",
    "adonis-preset-ts": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-adonis": "^1.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "pino-pretty": "^4.7.1",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.5",
    "youch": "^2.2.1",
    "youch-terminal": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@adonisjs/core": "^5.0.4-preview-rc-2.1",
    "@adonisjs/lucid": "^10.0.0",
    "@adonisjs/repl": "^1.1.6",
    "@adonisjs/session": "^4.0.6",
    "@adonisjs/view": "^3.1.0",
    "proxy-addr": "^2.0.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19"
  }
}
```

Comment: What command did you use to install `@adonisjs/lucid` (please share **full** command), thx

Comment: i used ```npm install @adonisjs/lucid@alpha``` for the installation

Comment: thank you, can you share your `package.json`, thx

Comment: My package.json file code has been updated into the question

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.
It seemed to happen when I updated the assembler.

I updated the following packages and it fixed it for me:

```
npm i @adonisjs/assembler@latest --save-dev
npm i @adonisjs/core@latest --save
```

If you notice your `package.json` you can see that you are on a preview release of the core package `"@adonisjs/core": "^5.0.4-preview-rc-2.1"`.

Hope this helped.